# Loading .dat file, data all fused into one

Tags: r

I have a simple problem. I have a .dat file, info seperated by single blank spaces. I am trying to load it with:

```
super=read.delim("Supermodel.dat", header=TRUE)
```

The result is that all the variables and all their names are compressed into one variable.

I copy-pasted the data into a notepad .txt file and executed:

```
super=read.delim("Supermodel.txt", header=TRUE)
```

The result was the same. I don't get it. Please help.

Comment: The file extension is purely cosmetic; it has no influence whatsoever on the contents and the parsing of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read.delim()` defaults to expecting tab characters (`\t`) as the delimiter.  Try `super=read.delim("Supermodel.txt", header=TRUE, sep=' ')` to tell the function to use spaces instead.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. I can only accept your answer in 10 minutes, at which point I shall do it!

Comment: `read.table` probably works as well, and might be more appropriate. But if you’re using `read.delim`, don’t set `header=TRUE`: it’s the default of that function anyway.